# How can I fill the circle when pressing on F in blender 2.83?

Tags: modeling

The tutorial is using blender 2.82

I added a circle and when I change it to edit mode and press on the F key instead filling the circle it's giving me this error :

This is the circle in object mode :

[image: Circle]

Then changing to edit mode and pressing F :

[image: No points were selected]

Following a tutorial when he press on F the result is :

[image: Tutorial filled circle]

I didn't see in the tutorial that he selected any points or how to do it.

Comment: pressing `F` makes a face in a mesh but your circle is a curve, so you need to convert it to a mesh first

Comment: I think you added a Bezier circle instead of a mesh circle.

Comment: Just go back to the beginning of the video "tutorial" and see what kind of object was created. Mesh and Curves are two different kind of objects

Comment: In my case, I converted the mesh into a curve and in the curve tap(opposite to what people suggested), there's a Shape options where you can choose the Fill Mode, select "both" and then update the material in the material tap and it should fill.